# Installing Aubio (python, windows)

Tags: python, windows, git, installation

I am having some trouble installing the aubio module for Python. According to the [website](http://aubio.org/), the following command typed into the command line should install the module:

```
pip install git+git://git.aubio.org/git/aubio
```

However, I only receive an error message "Cannot find git".

As the 2nd attempt, I downloaded the [source files](http://aubio.org/download) from the site, and again tried to install with PIP:

```
pip install c:/aubio #Anaconda32/sources as directory
```

I received an error message, "import error: no object named "gen_pyobject".

Finally I tried to use the exact method highlighted in the [installation guide](http://aubio.org/installation):

```
cd aubio
./waf configure build
```

Which returns an error message stating that waf is not an external or internal command or program.

I am running out of ideas, how can this extension actually be installed?

Comment: Have you tried installing/reinstalling Git? The Windows version can be found here: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Did you run the first snippet in the git bash under windows?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen I attempted that too now. Still returns an "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Comment: @Dole this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat article may be helpful

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter-Poulsen When installing (vcsetup), "Error 1719: The windows installer service could not be accessed".

Comment: Google gives: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-1719-windows-installer-service-could-not-be/a3d7a90f-5953-4b93-a536-d807e21e0b93?auth=1 for this error

Answer (score 0):

[aubio](https://aubio.org) should now build correctly on windows:

```
$ pip install aubio
```

it is being [continuously tested](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/piem/aubio/) for different windows configurations.

please [open a new issue](https://github.com/aubio/aubio/issues/new) if you encounter a problem.